# Substitute one table for another at runtime

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have 9 tables with state information in them. They all have the same field names. I have a Crystal Report that is based on one of them. I want the user to be able to select a state and change the Crystal Report to use that table instead of the one it was based on.I mean when user select text in combo box and then click on "OK" then report show (using only one rpt for all the tables of same fields).

How do I do that in VB.Net?

Answer (score 1):

Could you base the Report on a Stored Procedure and pass in a parameter so the Stored Procedure knows which table you want the data from?

I remember trying to get a Crystal Report (v2005) to switch database source from the one it was designed against and that wasn't easy - every table had the connection details in it if I recall correctly! (maybe changing tables is easier though)

Comment: i have the database name"Rajab" in which the all the tables have same fields and structures now the problem is that i have designed an rpt now i want that if user select any table from the list of combo box then through this rpt the data of every table shows. how can i use that rpt for every table because i don't want to use seperate rpt for every table i want to use only single designed rpt for 6 to 7 tables. now anyone there who can help me or not? Thanks for your co-operation. thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

It's not easier but if the tables have the same structure you should be able to do it. But you should create a new Document for it and call SetDataSource for your new table. After this you can set the document as ReportSource to your viewer.

Comment: i have a combo box which has a list of the tables i have alsoa new option there to create new table at runtime now when new table is created then after that i want to show the report of the current table .all the table have same structure and field.how can i do this with only single rpt. guide me through code please. vb.net code required for assistance. thanks

Comment: well assuming your Report is named report and your tables name is talble, than you just have to write "report.SetDataSource(report)"

Comment: i have done this report.setdatasource(mrreport) but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry but you have to show us some of your code - it's rather hard to tell were the error is otherwise